# PHPstorm autocomplete undefined variables

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm, usability

Let's say in example i have a controller with couple of actions.
In each action i define $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
I will like IDE to autocomplete it in every new action i am creating.

I am aware, that IDE could have two options:
- autocomplete each variable name defined in file
- or autocomplete each variable name defined in project

Is that possible?

Comment: Autocomplete in standard sense -- no. But you may use `Code | Completion | Cyclic Expand Word` actions for such stuff.

Comment: Nope, that's not what i want.
Cyclic Expand option has two flaws: it only expands text to first matched occurrence visible on screen, and don't give any choice. Thanks for your tip anyway :)

Comment: *"and don't give any choice"* Correct -- that's why I said "not in standard sense". *"it only expands text to first matched occurrence visible on screen"* If you use it again, it will offer next/previous match (that's why it called "cyclic").

Comment: BTW -- if you need to repeat certain part of code on regular basis (e.g. each action method will have similar starting code) then I suggest looking into Live Templates (snippets).

Comment: Sorry for my bad answer, but you're correct. I didn't use it in backwards mode, where i would find it's cycling. It does't loop what i was imply. On the other way i'am guessing why it doesn't hint anything, it will be better in functional way. Anyway it's doesn't fit my needs. Guess i have to look for an extension or write my own. Your tip about Live Templates could be a good starting point, but i'am afraid that i would end up spending most time coding LT and it wouldn't impact my work performance in the way that i want :)